# How can I align decimal in tabularray package?

Tags: tabularray

I am trying to align decimal in this table by using `tabularray` package. My code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={X[r]X[r]X[r]X[r]X[r]X[r]X[r]X[r]X[r]X[r]}}
        \num{48,5} & 43 & 50 & 55 & 45 & 60 & 53 & \num{55,5} & 44 & 65 \\
        51 & 62,5 & 41 & \num{44,5} & 57 & 57 & 68 & 49 & 46,5 & \num{53,5} \\
        61 & \num{49,5} & 54 & 62 & 59 & 56 & 47 & 50 & 60 & 61 \\
        \num{49,5} & \num{52,5} & 57 & 47 & 60 & 55 & 45 & \num{47,5} & 48 & \num{61,5}
        \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I align it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `tabularray` package has a dedicated library for siunitx. After loading this library, you can either use the traditional `S` column (which you might already know from siunitx) or you can use `si` in X or Q columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{diagbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec={
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
              X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]
            }}
        \num{48,5} & 43 & 50 & 55 & 45 & 60 & 53 & \num{55,5} & 44 & 65 \\
        51 & 62,5 & 41 & \num{44,5} & 57 & 57 & 68 & 49 & 46,5 & \num{53,5} \\
        61 & \num{49,5} & 54 & 62 & 59 & 56 & 47 & 50 & 60 & 61 \\
        \num{49,5} & \num{52,5} & 57 & 47 & 60 & 55 & 45 & \num{47,5} & 48 & \num{61,5}
        \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good. I'm unfamiliar with this package, but may want to use it sometimes. With the numbers in this example we could easily get this alignment by left aligning all the columns. Does your code work the same, if some of the entries have, say, one or three digits before the decimal separator? Or a minus sign?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You'll need to adjust the `table-format` to how many digits, minus signs etc. you have, see the siunitx documentation for details

Comment: Can we use `X[r,si={table-format=2.1}]` one time for all table?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 If you have a new question, please ask a new question