# Siuntix \num in combination with \input fails with "Argument of \@iinput has an extra }."

Tags: siunitx

I'm trying to make siunitx interpret a number stored in a separate file on disk, but `\num{\input{number.txt}}` fails with the following error message: `Argument of \@iinput has an extra }.` Is there another way to do this?

---

MWE (assuming a file called "number.txt" exists on disk and its content is a number such as 1 in my case):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\num{\input{number.txt}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is your need?

Comment: The greater context of my problem is that I have lots of numbers stored individually in tiny files that I would like to typeset into tables using the tabularray package and align to their decimal points. Decimal alignment in tabularray tables is discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/672546/182557, however, the only solution is based on siunitx and doesn't work in my case because I am inputting my numbers from files on disk. I know decimal alignment is easy with tabular(x) environments, but I already have my tables in place, so I prefer solutions that work with tabularray.

Comment: You should use `S` column not `\num`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file contents to a macro (`\tmp` in the example above) and then use it as a macro argument (but `\tmp` must be expanded by `\expandafter`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

{\catcode`\@=11
\gdef\readfile#1{{\endlinechar=-1 \everyeof={\end}\expandafter\readfileA\@@input{#1}}}
\gdef\readfileA#1\end{\gdef\tmp{#1}}
}

\begin{document}
\readfile{number.txt}\expandafter\num\expandafter{\tmp}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple example. You should read the doc of `tabularray` and `siunitx`.

`num.txt`:

```latex
6.618    & 287.1854 & 998.7116 & 163.1364 & 512.8064 & 291.2459 \\
518.5163 & 853.7523 & 80.038   & 94.076   & 271.9311 & 268.8729 \\
563.1559 & 20.6741  & 491.2001 & 665.8677 & 386.862  & 2.2473   \\
316.0299 & 614.1185 & 23.327   & 964.3642 & 238.9255 & 65.4116  \\
923.5761 & 944.643  & 155.7276 & 973.4626 & 951.6755 & 891.3304 \\
```

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}
[evaluate=\fileInput]
{
colspec={*{6}{Q[si={table-format=3.4},c,m]}},
hlines,vlines,
}
\fileInput{num.txt}
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]